# How to Enter Placeholder Text Within Html.TextBoxFor in C# / MVC 4

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Typically in HTML / CSS, if you want to add placeholder text to a textbox you would simply do this:

`<input type="text" class="input-class" placeholder="Please enter your email"/>`

But since I'm using the existing code that's provided for a login panel in Visual Studio MVC 4:

`/Views/Account/Login.cshtml`

This is the C# code that's currently rendering the inputs:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-input" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-input" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

[image]

How do you add placeholder text to this code in C#? I tried this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, placeholder ="Email" new { @class = "form-input" })
```

And it underlined 'placeholder' in red saying "The name 'placeholder' does not exist in the current context".

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use an overload of `TextBoxFor()` with an `htmlAttributes` argument. This argument should be an anonymous object with *all* attributes you wish to assign to the input.

For example, if you want to set the `placeholder` and `class` attributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Email, new { placeholder = "Email", @class = "form-input" } )
```

Answer (score 11):

Try to the following

> This code is tested and it's working

```
@Html.TextBox("CustomarName" ,null, new { @class = "form-control" , @placeholder = "Search With Customar Name" })
```

Hope it helps to you

Comment: OP is asking how to use placeholder in `TextBoxFor` not in the `TextBox`

Comment: That was an answer I was actually looking for :-)

Answer (score 6):

This works for me...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @placeholder = "Username", @class = "input100" })
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { placeholder = "Email" })
```

Comment: If I do this: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { placeholder = "Email" }, new { @class = "text-danger" })` it underlines `new { placeholder = "Email" }` in red and says "Argument 3: cannot convert from '<anonymous type: string placeholder>' to 'string'" - I think it still needs the `text-danger` class but I can try removing it. **Edit** Removing the class works - `text-danger` is a bootstrap class to define the placeholder text color. Actually, though, I would still like to define the placeholder text color.

Comment: You're actually creating a new object with `new  {placeholder = "Email"}`. So you can include any other html attributes that you want; neither of them is mandatory. You can even keep it blank.

Answer (score 4):

**For input field**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Email, new { placeholder = "Your email id" })
```

**For textarea**

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { placeholder = "Please add description here" })
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a parameter which is objecthtmlattributes , You can set every html input attribute there 

Example:

```
 @Html.TextBox("Model binding here" , new { @class="form-controll" , @placeholder="Enter email"})
```