# CSS working fine for HTML but not Razor syntax

Tags: html, css, razor

I'm making a contact form, at first it was pure html:

```
<div id="contact-container">
<form class="cf">
    <div class="half left cf">
        <input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email address">
        <input type="tel" id="input-phone" placeholder="Phone">
        <input type="text" id="input-subject" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
    <div class="half right cf">
        <textarea name="message" type="text" id="input-message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit">
</form>
</div>
```

However when I converted it to Razor syntax:

```
<div id="contact-container">
@Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Service", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "cf" })
{
    <div class="half left cf">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlattributes = new { id = "input-name", placeholder = "Name" }})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { htmlattributes = new { id = "input-email", placeholder = "Email Address" }})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone, new { htmlattributes = new { id = "input-phone", placeholder = "Phone" }})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject, new { htmlattributes = new { id = "input-subject", placeholder = "Subject" }})
    </div>
    <div class="half right cf">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message, new { htmlattributes = new { id = "input-message", placeholder = "Message" }})
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit">
}
</div>
```

It looks completely different, with random text such as `System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm {` and a bunch of semicolons on the web page.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `using` around the form creation, for example:

```
<div id="contact-container">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Service", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "cf" })
{
    <div class="half left cf">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlattributes = new { id = "input-name", placeholder = "Name" }})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { htmlattributes = new { id = "input-email", placeholder = "Email Address" }})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone, new { htmlattributes = new { id = "input-phone", placeholder = "Phone" }})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject, new { htmlattributes = new { id = "input-subject", placeholder = "Subject" }})
    </div>
    <div class="half right cf">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message, new { htmlattributes = new { id = "input-message", placeholder = "Message" }})
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit">
}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was it, any reason the placeholder text isn't showing up now though?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44013787/1663001