# Html TextBoxFor with validation

Tags: html, validation

I have the following which results in a red validation message appearing under the TextBoxFor if it is not populated.  This works fine but what I'd rather have is the validation message appearing where the TextBoxFor placholder is.

Is there a way to do that within html?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Username, new { type = "email", id = "emailEntry", placeholder = "Email address..", @class = "form-control" })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.Username, "Email address is required", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013663/how-to-enter-placeholder-text-within-html-textboxfor-in-c-sharp-mvc-4 You may want to overload `TextBoxFor()` with the validation message as a new placeholder?

Comment: Thanks for the input, had thought of that but if it is do able then I can't quite get the syntax, need to do a bit of digging...

Comment: A placeholder text is only shown when there is no input (yet), so even you could get it to work, it will be a rather useless approach if you also have validation for the scenario where there is input - those placeholder-errors will never appear due to *input being present*.